# "Battery not fully charged"

Tags: grammar

When I shut off the charging plug of my mobile , before the mobile was fully charged, it showed

> "battery not fully charged."

As far as basic grammar is concerned, this should have been "battery is not fully charged." Is that correct?

Comment: If it's what is said, there's nothing wrong.  It could have said "battery is glopnipd" and the grammar of the sentence would still be valid.  Remember that what is quoted is not subject to grammar rules, if it represents what really was said.

Comment: It is a form a verb phrase ellipsis used by robots and computers. Historically humans have assumed that computers and robots should not be able to talk all that well. Now that they can, we still make them speak like that. For example: 'Systems down!'.

Comment: Omission of words like *the* and *is*, which can easily be inferred, is sometimes called “telegraphic” language, from a medium where the sender paid for each word.

Answer (score 2):

"Battery not fully charged," as you have accurately observed, is NOT a complete sentence, but it is not grammatically incorrect within the context.  Titles are not complete sentences and this falls into that category.  This kind of general statement, though, is not considered incorrect grammatically

Comment: Yes, it's a warning or status message and, as such, is similar to a road sign. Signs which say things like "Ice on road", "Caution falling rocks" or "Danger, mines" are stripped back to transmit the message as efficiently as possble so grammar is a secondary consideration.

Comment: Yes,this is definitely not a title, but falls into the category of signage. And not just road signs and not even just warning signs, but any signage in general. "Under construction", "no trespassing", "life vest under seat", "fresh grapes today", "disabled parking only", and any number of others for every conceivable occasion and purpose.